# Помогите решить задачу на строки

Tags: java

Задание такое.
Я ввожу строку. Например Мама. Мне нужно вывести на консоль в столбик:

```
М
Ма
Мам
Мама
```

Я пробовал так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    for (int j )
    System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: Вам нужен скорее `substring`

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужен скорее `substring`, которая возвращает подстроку данной строки. Подстрока начинается с символа, заданного индексом, и продолжается до конца данной строки или до `endIndex-1`, если введен второй аргумент.

Синтаксис метода:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex)
```

или

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

- `beginIndex` — начальный индекс, включительно;
- `endIndex` — конечный индекс, не включая.

---

Получается так, что на каждой итерации у нас начало строки (индекс) будет всегда одно и то же (0), а индекс конца равен значению счётчика + 1 (т.к. он начинается с нуля, а если взять у строки подстроку длиной ноль - это будет пустая строка)

---

```
String s = "Мама";
        
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, i + 1));
}
```